# C# Compare multiple string values

Tags: c#

I make a simple diagnostic for the car whit ELM327.And i can read a fault codes ,and compare values of received fault end post the result int the text box but how can i compare the received value and not tu use so many (IF) in the code..I try use a text file whit the list of fault codes but only i found the example where the return value is true or false. Example if i received the fault 0400 and i want to compare that value exist on list of codes i make and when found that fault add some text that explain that fault code. I hope you understand me. Sorry for my bad english

I was not able to find a single independent example of how to solve it. Thanks for your help